# kendo ui upload onComplete context in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, kendo-ui

I use AngularJS and kendo upload widjet.

Html markup:

```
<input name="files"
    kendo-upload
    type="file"
    k-complete="vm.onFilesUploadComplete"/>
```

Controller:

```
class MyController{
   constructor(){
      this.myImportantVar = false;
   }

   onFilesUploadComplete{
        this.myImportantVar = true; // << here 'this' points to another context, not to MyController
    }
}
```

vm - is alias for MyController.

Complete event fires, but inside event handler I can't get access to 'myImportantVar', because 'this' points to another, not MyController, context (some angular's context), and I can't continue.

How do I access the 'myImportantVar'?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) to get the controller:

```
class MyController{
   constructor(){
      this.myImportantVar = false;
   }

   onFilesUploadComplete{
       var elem = angular.element(this);
       var vm = elem.controller(); 
       vm.myImportantVar = true; // << here 'this' points to another context, not to MyController
   }
}
```

For more information, see [AngularJS element function API Reference - jQuery/jqLite Extras](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#jquery-jqlite-extras).

Comment: Is any way to perform event handler execution in MyController context? elem.controller() doesn't give me pointer to MyController